# How to prevent background color from hiding part of italicized text

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to prevent the background color of "search" from hiding part of the "e" to left of it (see code snippet)?

I still want the background color and "e" to overlap, but I want the "e" to be on top of the background color. I'm looking for a way to do this with **only css** and **without changing the font-family**. However, if that's not possible, I'm open to a solution that involves changing the html markup.

I'm also looking for a general solution that could work for any word (e.g. highlighting "nas" in "gymnasts")

```css
body {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.highlighted {
  background: yellow
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="italic">Re<span class="highlighted">search</span>ers</div></br>
<div class="italic">Gym<span class="highlighted">nas</span>ts</div>
```

Comment: @duplicate_closer not sure how the duplicate question is relevant, care to explain if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adjust `z-index` like below:

```css
body {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.highlighted {
  background: yellow;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0; /*To create a stacking context and be sure the negative z-index won't go below the parent*/
}
```

```html
<div class="italic">Re<span class="highlighted">search</span>ers</div><br>
<div class="italic">Gym<span class="highlighted">nas</span>ts</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is now working. you just have to get the first word into the div. there is no other way.

```css
body {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.highlighted {
  background: yellow
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.first {
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="italic"><div class="first">Re</div><span class="highlighted">search</span>ers</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what you fixed instead of just fixing it (not the downvoter)

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but you could improve its quality. Explain your answer, use proper grammar and don't discourage anyone else by saying "there is no other way."